# Google Data Studio (BigQuery) - Create filter to select by latest hour

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-data

I have a columns DATE, TIME (only hour number) and GROSSVALUE

```
DATE          TIME     GROSSVALUE
2018-09-12    13       734564
2018-09-12    12       234324
```

How to use Scorecard to display GROSSVALUE for the current and previous hour?

**IF currently is 2018-09-12 (and any time between 13:00 to 13:59)**

**EXAMPLE:**

```
--------------
```

**CURRENT**

```
________________
|              |
|   734564     |
|______________|
```

**PREVIOUS**

```
________________
|              |
|   234324     |
|______________|
```

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

Does the BigQuery LAG() function get what you're after?
Something like:

```
SELECT GROSSVALUE
   , LAG()GROSSVALUE AS GROSSVALUE_last_hour
FROM DATASOURCE
ORDER BY DATE
   , TIME
```